# What's the proper way to indicate Drupal version

Tags: discussion

I actually had two separate users tell me they wished I had provided context about the version I was inquiring about on this question: [How to sum two fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232539/how-to-sum-two-fields/232548)

One user even told me to tag it `7`.

To which I scratched my head and thought, "well, I did"

And I did! But it was removed by a moderator.

So, what's the proper way to indicate a version.

Comment: Ok. So my question was really only for 7. An answer for 8 wouldn't matter to me. If someone wanted to add an 8 answer for funzies then fine. Actually I've added 7 answers to 6 questions in the past. But the version tag should be added to quickly add critical context to what the OP wants help with, which is why a question is being asked in the first place. I don't understand having my 7 tag removed by a moderator. Questioners want to add context and Answerers want that context. I'm not sure I see the issue.

Comment: The answer doesn't change, whenever you are asking for [tag:7] or [tag:8]. We don't need the same question asked for each Drupal version, when it isn't specific for a version.

Comment: I guess it comes down to what does the individual questioner want versus what the community wants. If I didn't tag that question as 7 and I only got 8 answers, I'd be unsatisfied. I'm not sure it's a problem to have seemingly duplicate questions for the various versions of Drupal because there can be so much that is different in a potential solution.

Comment: There is not need to tag a question [tag:7] just to mean _I am using Drupal 7_: Just say it in the question body. A question like "How do I set a path alias?" doesn't need to be asked twice just because a user is using Drupal 7 and the other one is using Drupal 8; plus, we don't need another question yet asked by a user who is using Drupal 9 or Drupal 10.

Comment: Why have a tag for `7` at all then? Why even allow that tag ever?

What's the difference between asking a question and mentioning "I am using Drupal 7" and tagging it 7? The result is the same in terms of your worry of duplicates. Tagging 7 is just quicker *and* allows for filtering.

Also, I would argue that having "duplicate" questions for *some* questions in Drupal based on version is the lesser of two evils - and in some cases is worthwhile because the answers can vary so much. 

And how would you mark a correct answer? Do we need multiple checkboxes? One for 7, 8, 9 and beyond?

Comment: Just a little note: Accepting an answer doesn't mark it as correct, but marks it as _the most helpful answer the OP found between the given answers for the question, at the time the answer was accepted_. Just the user who asked the question can accept an answer, but answer can be up-voted from all the users with the privilege of up-voting; 10 up-votes give more than getting the answer accepted.